# Optimize source structure for C++ projects

Tags: c++

I would like to create a little project, which is divided in more then one file.
main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include sc_hpp

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    add(3,4);
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

sc.hpp:

```
#ifndef "sc.hpp"
#define sc_hpp

int add(int a, int b);



#endif
```

function.cpp:

```
#include "sc.hpp"

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return(a + b);
}
```

But it doesn't work.
ERROR:

```
`add' undeclared (first use this function)
```

First time I'm trying make programme in more then one file, so I think the problem must be easy to solve.

Comment: `#include sc_hpp` should be `#include "sc.hpp"` and `#ifndef "sc.hpp"` should be `#ifndef sc_hpp`.

Comment: Still doesn't work.Error:unterminated #ifndef , error: macro names must be identifiers

Comment: Well, you must have messed up in some other way.

Comment: Ok.I found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two obvious mistakes:

In your `main`:

```
     #include <cstdlib>
     #include <iostream>
     // the included header file needs to be enclosed in " " 
     // and it needs a suffix, i.e.: `.h`
     #include "sc_hpp.h"

     using namespace std;

     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {

     }
```

In `sc.hpp:`

```
    // the include guards doesn't have to be enclosed in " "
    // the suffix's dot:'.' is replaced with underscore: '_'
    // header name in uppercase letters
    #ifndef SC_HPP_H
    #define SC_HPP_H

    int add(int a, int b);

    //  included .cpp files with function implementation here
    #include "sc.hpp"

    #endif
```

More on how to organize code files, [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798).

In general the preprocessor directive `#include` expands the code contained in the file that follows it, so your code in `main` looks like this:

```
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <iostream>
   // #include "sc_hpp.h" replaced with
   int add(int a, int b);
   // the #include "sc.cpp" nested within the "sc_hpp.h" is replaced with
   int add(int a, int b)
   {
       return(a + b);
   }

   using namespace std;

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {

   }
```

Comment: Do I have make a project to make programs in multi files?